# Bootstrap Media Queries Inside a Selector in a LESS Import?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm trying to apply Bootstrap to a specific div. To do this, I'm importing the Boostrap LESS files as follows:

```
.bootstrap_wrap {
    @import 'bootstrap/bootstrap.less'; 
    @import 'bootstrap/responsive.less';    
}
```

However, doing so seems to break media queries.

Is there any way to selectively apply Boostrap without breaking media queries within the Boostrap CSS?

Comment: I would consider only importing the less files that you need (modals.less, alerts.less, etc. whatever) rather than the entire library. If you don't want the media queries affected especially, remove the `responsive.less` because that is it's primary function.

Comment: That does seem to be the best option for this specific instance. I'm also wondering if this is a more general solution for this -- e.g. a way to wrap less imports without affecting media queries. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Slowly integrating Bootstrap into an existing site. Don't want to apply it to everything during first round.

Comment: @bfromsd you wouldn't need the responsiveness if you apply the framework only to part of the website because responsiveness is based on the full screen width and the interaction of all the elements of the page, would you ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me if you are compiling this or using less.js

I'm able to compile it without errors (using Codekit), and the results look good, just make sure the paths are correct.

If I create a new bootstrap_wrap.less file with

```
.bootstrap_wrap {
@import 'bootstrap.less';
@import 'responsive.less';
```

}

and place it in the same directory as the other bootstrap less files, then compile it this is the result:
[bootstrap_wrap.css](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2665617/bootstrap_wrap.css)

The results look promising to me, for example I see:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.bootstrap_wrap #footer {
margin-left: -20px;
margin-right: -20px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
}
}
```

Good luck!